# How to call component on button click in React js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-typescript

In React Js when I call child component within Parent component then component call render time but I want to call child component when I will click on button  then call child component .
I don't want to use routing.

I tried Props and context API but It is nor worked properly.

Comment: Can you share the example code for our reference?

Comment: If you want to show a single element you can use showChild ? <ChildComponent> : null, does that not work for your use case

Comment: Just add Boolean state to false default and make it true on click... Make your component display using if condition..Please share your code for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

do this
create a state which initially is false
and with component which you call make it conditional with optional chaining
and the button onclick changes the state to true so the component is rendered

something like this

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const abc = () => {
    const [isrendered,setisrendered]=useState(false);
  return (
    <div>abc</div>
    <input type="button" onClick={()=>{setisrendered(true)}} />click this to show component
    {isrendered&&<Thecomponent/>}
  )
}

export default abc
```

Comment: please mark it as correct answer if it worked and feel free to ask any questions